# How can I implement this equation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

So I am trying to implement the Modified Steinmetz Equation to calculate losses in electro motors in MATLAB. Generally speaking, Steinmetz equations always require parameter fitting, so I planned to do this with the lsqcurvefit method from matlab. I got a vector `P` for meassured losses and also the steinmetz equation (eq. 1.6 in the screenshot). `B` and `f_r` are also available meassurement datas and descsribe the flux density and the frequency. In adition, `ΔB` describes the peak-to-peak value from the vector `B`.
I think my problems occur somewhere in the differentiation of eq. 1.3
[Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoWhp.png)
Also, as you can see in the plot, I use 3 cycles with constant frequencies and want to fit the parameters to all of them so I get the best overall fit. But if I do it in one single approach, I get those weird "jumps" from the last datapoint of one cycle to the beginning of the new one. How can I tune the fitting process to avoid this, since it also increases the error I would assume?

Here is my code:

```
%% Data
f = [50*ones(1,20),100*ones(1,20), 200*ones(1,20)];
B = [0.129005, 0.20941, 0.285675, 0.351604, 0.420301, 0.472229, 0.519726, 0.557796, 0.632096, 0.694707, 0.751395, 0.798734, 0.847072, 0.935783, 1.00459, 1.10803, 1.17043, 1.26289, 1.32085, 1.39043, 0.107179, 0.174887, 0.246718, 0.315502, 0.377646, 0.434447, 0.48719, 0.534519, 0.615403, 0.686914, 0.749896, 0.802816, 0.848392, 0.939327, 1.00829, 1.10413, 1.16865, 1.26479, 1.32219, 1.39146, 0.0454491, 0.135779, 0.191237, 0.250392, 0.308418, 0.363068, 0.415588, 0.463521, 0.567148, 0.633874, 0.703828, 0.781288, 0.830133, 0.943621, 1.01134, 1.11057, 1.17113, 1.26619, 1.32158, 1.39049];
P = [3.56019e+06, 8.84152e+06, 1.58958e+07, 2.32735e+07, 3.24114e+07, 4.02276e+07, 4.80373e+07, 5.47367e+07, 6.89596e+07, 8.20459e+07, 9.45857e+07, 1.06421e+08, 1.18526e+08, 1.44977e+08, 1.67979e+08, 2.12126e+08, 2.45933e+08, 3.16602e+08, 3.77042e+08, 4.81213e+08, 6.11187e+06, 1.58769e+07, 3.02953e+07, 4.77948e+07, 6.65968e+07, 8.61983e+07, 1.06581e+08, 1.26867e+08, 1.65843e+08, 2.04851e+08, 2.43487e+08, 2.7937e+08, 3.1219e+08, 3.86163e+08, 4.53843e+08, 5.75776e+08, 6.8676e+08, 9.00309e+08, 1.09415e+09, 1.4061e+09, 2.97628e+06, 2.6358e+07, 5.0618e+07, 8.37086e+07, 1.23124e+08, 1.66368e+08, 2.13396e+08, 2.61076e+08, 3.80119e+08, 4.6843e+08, 5.71166e+08, 7.01623e+08, 7.92223e+08, 1.04094e+09, 1.23529e+09, 1.60757e+09, 1.931e+09, 2.63402e+09, 3.1432e+09, 4.06547e+09];

%% Init
T = 1./f;
dt = T ./ 1000;
dB = diff(B); dB = [dB dB(end)]; % flux density differential
B_pp = max(B) - min(B); % peak-to-peak flux density

%% Fitting
%inital parameter guesses
x0 = [0,1.5,3];
% Define function to fit (modified Generalized Steinmetz Equation (MSE))
f_eq = sum((dB./dt).^2).*dt.* 2/(B_pp*pi)^2; %eq. (1.3) 
MSE = @(x,B) (x(1).*f_eq.^(x(2)-1).*B.^x(3)).*f; %eq. (1.6) 

%fit parameters
[x, resnorm, residual]  = lsqcurvefit(MSE, x0, B, P);

func = MSE(x, B);

figure; plot(B, P, 'bo', B, func, 'r-'); grid on;
xlabel('Magnetic field B [T]'); ylabel('Power loss p [W/m^3]');
legend('Experimental data', 'Fitted function'); title('Experimental vs. fitted');
set(gcf, 'Position', [0, 453, 500, 330]);
```

And a screenshot of the plot:
[Plot for meassurement data (blue) vs. fitted curve (red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sisle.jpg)